# How to install and use pyspark on mac

Tags: pyspark, installation

I'm taking a machine learning course and am trying to install pyspark to complete some of the class assignments.  I downloaded pyspark from this [link](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/#files), unzipped it and put it in my home directory, and added the following lines to my .bash_profile.

```
export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6 
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter" 
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

However, when I try to run the command:

```
pyspark
```

to start a session, I get the error:

```
-bash: pyspark: command not found
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get pyspark working on my local machine?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the PATH entry. Here are the environment variable changes I did to get pyspark working on my Mac:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home/
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON='jupyter'
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook --no-browser --port=8889'
```

Also ensure that, you've Java SE 8+ and Python 3.5+ installed.

Start the server from `/opt/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-master.sh`.
Then run `pyspark` and copy+paste URL displayed on screen in web browser.

Comment: I tried that.  I also checked my version of Python on my computer.  Its Python 2.7.16.  I never installed it, it came with my mac.  Is there a way to update it or should I try to download 3.5 from the internet